# Change Format LeftIndent value

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

What's the safest way to set the LeftIndent of a Paragraph.Format to lets' say 0.38" ??

Trying

```
  Paragraph parag = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
  parag.Range.Text = "bla bla bla";
  parag.Format.LeftIndent = Convert.ToSingle("0.38");
```

But the text show NOT indented to the Left !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Paragraph.LeftIndent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.leftindent%28v=office.11%29.aspx) Property:

> Returns or sets a Single that represents the left indent value (**in
>   points**) for the specified paragraphs, table rows, or HTML division.

What you need is to convert the value in points. The value you pass is too small.

You can use the [InchesToPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.inchestopoints%28v=office.11%29.ASPX) method or the [CentimetersToPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.centimeterstopoints%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method to convert measurements from inches or centimeters. These methods are available from the `Word.Application` object.